# ruby composition - how to show members of the composed class?

Tags: ruby, composition

Coming from rails where I am used to the rails framework managing relationships for me.

Now trying to just do basic Ruby.

Trying to understand relationships and composition.
Using Pack of Cards as an example.
For now just using a card_number of 1 to 52 (ignoring suit and real number for now).

The code below can create the PackOfCards, but isn't creating the 5 cards that I want, either nothing displays or I get a nil for the puts at the end.

```
class PackOfCards

  attr_accessor :pack_name, :cards

  def initialize(pack_name)

    @pack_name= pack_name
    cards = []
    5.times do
      cards << PlayingCard.new(self)
    end 
  end 

end

class PlayingCard

  attr_accessor :pack, :card_number

  def initialize(pack)
    @card_number = rand(52)
    @pack = pack
  end 

end

my_pack=PackOfCards.new('bobs')
puts my_pack.pack_name
puts my_pack.cards # Nothing
my_pack.cards.each do |one_card|
  puts one_card.card_number # Undefined method 'each' for nil
end
```

How can I create the pack of cards and have it have 5 cards when I do so and how can I display those 5 cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that accessor only create the `cards` and `cards=` methods for you. I don't think that `<<` should work. Try changing to:

```
@cards = []
5.times do
  @cards << PlayingCard.new(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in fact lies with the unintended local variable that you create.

If you said:

x = cards

It would be the same as:

x = self.cards

However without self on assignment you actually create a local variable 'cards'

self.cards = []

cards << foo

Will work fine, as use of a method will as per ruby look up on self first, but as local variables in ruby look the same as a method call, ruby can create them when assigning.